# Proof that primitive cells all have the same volume?

Tags: crystals

Given some area that can tile 2d space and which contains 1 point of a lattice and given a second area that also only contains 1 lattice point and can tile the whole space how can i prove they are equal areas?

Comment: What would happen if they didn't have the same area/volume?

Comment: In my opinion this is a math question.

Comment: @JonCuster if one was larger it would overlap with itself, if it were smaller it wouldn't be able to tile the space. it's intuitively obvious but i have a hard time formalizing it because it's true that you could have separate tilings where the tiles are different sizes, but something about the fact that they each capture only one lattice point forbids this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a fact you know is false, a good strategy is to try using that fact to create a contradiction. Here is an outline.

Assume you have two primitive cells of different areas that tile the plane while containing one lattice point each.

Find the circles that circumscribe each primivitive cell, and note their diameters.

Draw a large circle and fill most of it with lattice points. Leave lattice points near the edge out so that both circumscribing circles can roll around the inside of the large circle without hitting a lattice point.

Tile the lattice points both ways. Both tilings fit entirely inside the large circle. Both use the same number of cells (the same as the number of lattice points.) You can calculate the areas of the tilings. You can calculate the area of the circle.

If the circle is large, the tilings almost fill the circle. By making it larger and larger, you can make the small tiling fill as large a fraction of the circle as you like.

The ratio of the areas of the tilings must be the same as the ratio of the primitive cell areas. You can use this to show that you can find a large circle where the area of the large tiling > area of the circle. But since the large tiling must fit inside the circle, the area of the large tiling < area of the circle.

Comment: is this essentially the argument? 1 < (area of large tile) / (area of small tile) $\approx$ (area of large tile) / (area of circle) < 1

Comment: More or less. N * area of large tile / area of circle